# Convert erlang terms to string, or decode erlang binary

Tags: erlang

I have an erlang program which generates data.  This data needs to be transferred via udp to a non-erlang program for further processing.  I already have this part working - sending the data via udp and receiving it on the other non-erlang side.

Here's the problem.  The data (erlang terms like tuples containing lists) doesn't seem to be able to go over "as is" (i.e. I can't just send arbitrary erlang terms).  It apparently needs to be converted to either text or binary first.  Converting to binary seems easy enough with a bif I found.  The problem is, binary gobbledygook comes out the other side, and I don't know any easy way to decode it (the other side is non-erlang).

Barring someone telling me some easy way to decode binary gobbledygook on the other side, I'd like the data to be sent as a simplistic string representation of the terms - for instance a tuple like this:

```
{[1,2,3],[4,5,6]}
```

sent like this:

```
"{[1,2,3],[4,5,6]}"
```

I haven't seen any such bif, i.e. "convert_term_to_ascii/1" etc.  I know I could scan it and send token representations of the terms, but I don't want to do that - decoding that on the other side is just a pain I don't want to deal with.

I know I'm not the first, second, or third person to have this problem.  It has to be fairly common.  How is it normally dealt with?

Can someone point me to some resource showing me how to either 1) convert binary gobbledygook to ascii (needed on the non-erlang side), or 2) straightforwardly convert terms to a string (needed on the erlang side)?

Or, tell me how I'm wrong and how I should really be doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1) you can convert any term to string using

```
R= io_lib:format("~p",[yourtermhere]),
lists:flatten(R)
```

2) you might look at erlang external binary format, a lot of other languages have libraries for encode/decode that erlang binaries format. And in erlang you can encode any term by term_to_binary

Comment: Just ran into a related issue, converting a binary or string of the form that would be valid input for file:consult/1 into Erlang terms, but not starting from a file. I decided to document the solution for my future self, maybe others will find it helpful: http://zxq9.com/archives/1354

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend converting the erlang terms into JSON, with either of known libraries (heard good words regarding [rfc4267](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2007/02/17/json-and-json-rpc-for-erlang)). It'd be a trivial task to convert JSON back with any non-erlang platform, I guess. )

Comment: Another Erlang JSON library worth looking at is jsx - I use this for all Erlang server -> C++ client stuff and it's fast, reliable and easy to use.

Comment: Before deciding on JSON, keep in mind that there is no mapping between Erlang and JSON types. In particular, JSON (and YAML) lacks atoms, a direct representation of binary data, and a distinction among numbers-as-strings (and within that float vs integer). You have to pick an intermediate format or schematic translation to distinguish strings from binaries from lists, and atoms from strings, and each JSON lib will do it a bit differently. The BIFs `term_to_binary/1` <-> `binary_to_term/1` are exact and also work with BERT libraries ( http://bert-rpc.org/ ) for various languages.