# Erlang Tuple to String

Tags: erlang

Is there a way how to convert a tuple to a string ?

Consider I have the following list :

```
[{atom,5,program},{atom,5,receiving},{nil,5}]
```

I wish to convert this into  the following string:

```
"{atom,5,program},{atom,5,receiving},{nil,5}"
```

I have tried using erlang:tuple_to_list on each element in the list, which returns

```
A = [atom,5,program]
```

Eventually, I can't concatenate that with "{" ++ A ++ "}"

Any ideas how I can turn that to a string ?

Comment: the answer looks to be there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423488/convert-erlang-terms-to-string-or-decode-erlang-binary

Answer (score 15):

```
Term = [{atom,5,program},{atom,5,receiving},{nil,5}].
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Term])).
```

Comment: if lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Term])) returns multiline string then use "~999p" for otp <21 and use "~0p" for 21