# Erlang: getting record field values

Tags: erlang, field, record

I would like to know if there's an internal function in Erlang, similar to the one posted below, that will give me the record field values instead of the record field names.

```erlang
record_info(fields, RecordName).
```

Comment: Would something like `tl(tuple_to_list(Record))` work for you?

Comment: See http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-January/024666.html for how record_info/2 *pseudo* function is implemented.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear. This line will give me a string of field names, separated by ";" : string:join([atom_to_list(Field) || Field <- record_info(fields, RecordName)], ";")). What I want is almost the same, but with the values instead of the field names.

Comment: So it should be something like this? `string:join([lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [T])) || T <-tl(tuple_to_list(Record))], ";")`

Comment: See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423488/convert-erlang-terms-to-string-or-decode-erlang-binary about the generic conversion of an Erlang term into a string.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I appreciate it.

Comment: jj1bdx, thanks a million.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A record in Erlang is really a tuple with it's first element being the name of the record. After compilation is done, the record will be seen as a tuple.

If you have this record definition:

```
-record(name, [field, anotherfield]).
```

Then you can define a value of that record type like so:

```
#name{ field = value1, anotherfield = value2 }.
```

However, the actual representation for this under the hood is this:

```
{name, value1, value2}.
```

Note that the field names are actually gone here.

Now, if you want a list of the values for each field in the record, you can use `tuple_to_list`:

```
[name, value1, value2] = tuple_to_list(Record).
```

So, as jj1bdx pointed out, if you want a `;` separated string of all the values, you could do something like this:

```
string:join([lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [T])) || T <- tl(tuple_to_list(Record))], ";").
```

This last code snippet is stolen directly from jj1bdx.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your effort in clarifying this for me.

Comment: I hope this helps. If it answers your question and, unless there is something more I can answer, feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

`Record` in `record_info(fields, Record) -> [Field]` cannot be a variable, because it must be fixed at the compile time.

If you need to handle the elements in a key-value structure dynamically, use [maps](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html).

Comment: It was just a representation. It really reads like this: record_info(fields, order_info) -> [Field].  Thank you for your reply